# Save Page Locally and retain it when page request

Tags: javascript, html

My project has lot of pages. Most of the pages are static. Changes are very rare. So I think there is no need for server request on each page request. Can I save the page locally to avoid page requesting to server? So if the page is saved locally, we can retain its html content from the local storage on page request and display the page. Can I do this? Is it affecting the performance? Can u suggest best method to do this? Our project is in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: IF you store page on local only then at first time when any request comes to the server, there will be lots of content it will load to the local. It may slow down your speed of loading pages.

Comment: If there are many pages you should go with requesting server for every page.. You can also group some of the relative pages and load them in per request per group fasion and use JavaScript to hide and show them within group on demand. if there are less number of pages you can load then in single go and use JavaScript to hide and show on demand.

Comment: Maybe you should try local caching http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Grouping of page is not possible in our project. because it is hard for unit testing and other purpose. My requirement is saving the page on the first request and retain the page on further requests. i saw on some web application that on back button click pages are not actually post backing. this is the requirement i need.